# How to generate and activate autoloads for local packages?

Tags: package, package-repositories, package-development, autoload

It is clear that not all local/custom/personal packages should be officially released, and it would be silly to do so just to benefit from built-in package management support.  I'm wondering how to generate and activate autoloads for local packages?  That is similar to how `package.el` does it for the installed packages from ELPA.  In order to avoid reinventing the wheel, is there a way for it to "pretend" that some local directory (with subdirectories each of which is a local/custom/personal package) is ELPA?  I'm also open to `el-get` if such a scenario can be supported via, for example, custom recipes.

I'm sure the task is pretty common and anybody who uses Emacs on advanced level comes to that point sooner or later.  Could anybody share their experiences in this field?

Comment: `update-directory-autoloads` can be used independently of any package manager.

Comment: @npostavs, I know but it's not recursive and it's not a comprehensive solution in this case.  For sure it will be not enough and I would have to wrap it into my own implementation.

Comment: 1. You can provide a list of dirs (e.g., a dir and its descendants) to `update-directory-autoloads`, to, in effect, make it recursive. 2. You can use `update-file-autoloads` for every file you are interested in, regardless of which directory it is in.

Comment: FYI: `package.el` is also non-recursive (i.e., it doesn't support packages with sources in subdirectories).

Comment: I set up a local MELPA on Linux. I don't have any good solution for windows. I really wish emacs would support this type of thing out of the box. Might be worth checking use-package to see if it can.

Comment: @eflanigan00, `use-package` can't do that, I know for sure.

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution (IMO) is to use a package manager which has explicit support for this use case. This would be [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), which I wrote for this purpose.

You can read verbose documentation, including comparisons to other package managers, in the [README](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el), so I'll stick to how you can use `straight.el` to solve your specific problem.

1. Place your repository in `~/.emacs.d/straight/repos/<my-repo>`.
2. Load it using

   ```
   (straight-use-package '(<my-package> :local-repo "<my-repo>"))
   ```
3. You're done. Whenever you make changes to the source code, autoload generation and byte-compilation will be redone (at next Emacs startup). You also get things like dependency management, optional version control automation, etc. for free.
4. When (if) you want to publish the package, just push it somewhere and modify the recipe to point to that Git repository.
5. You can also use `straight.el` with `use-package` if you prefer (it's just syntax sugar for the most part).

Answer (score 3):

If you have replaced an already installed package with a different version, and all you are missing is the autoloads file, you can use package-generate-autoloads to generate it:

```
(package-generate-autoloads "async" "~/.emacs.d/elpa/async-1.9.3/")
```

I found it easier then using update-directory-autotools when I need to downgrade a package to an earlier version.

Actually I think I have not really answered your question.  I'll leave this answer here for the time being but my answer is more relevant here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348561/how-to-generate-autoloads-for-elpa-packages/50100170

Answer (score 2):

I do the following on Linux:

I setup a local melpa repository by cloning melpa.

I modify the recipes I want to point to my local packages. The following is `local-melpa/recipies/ace-window`

```
(ace-window
  :url "/home/my_home/.emacs.d/packages/ace-window/"
  :fetcher git)
```

Then from local-mepla type `make all` or `make recipies/ace-window` to build the package(s) in `local-melpa/packages`

Then `make packages/archive-contents`, which populates the list of packages.

Then in use to following to tell emacs to use my local melpa

```
(setq package-archives '(("local-melpa" . "~/.emacs.d/packages/local-melpa/packages/")))
```

I haven't figured out how to run `make` on windows. But I can build the packages in `local-melpa` on Linux and copy it over to windows and emacs understands and installs the packages properly.

The benefit of this is I can reset anytime I want by deleting my `~/.emacs.d/elpa/*` directory and installing any custom updates to any package.

Comment: Perhaps [quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa) would also be of interest?

Comment: I think you are right npostavs. I have to sit down and look at it.