# How to use package-generate-autoloads

Tags: package, autoload

I am teaching myself  autoloads for "home-made" packages.

[Official Docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html)
suggest to  use `update-file-autoloads` or `update-directory-autoloads` on the related package file or directory, which will add the corresponding autoload calls into `loaddefs.el`. This does not seem to be the strategy followed by most packages, which instead create a distinct `*-autoloads.el` file for each source equipped with the *magic autoload comments*  (perhaps to avoid cluttering `loaddefs.el`).

I haven't found any tutorial on this, by the way a user [suggested](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/41274/3975) to use `package-generate-autoloads`. Indeed, it works up to a certain point, and this is my attempt.

I created the file `...site-lisp/foo/foo.el`:

```el
;;;###autoload
(defun foofunc () (message "I'm foo"))
(provide 'foo)
```

Then, I executed on the `foo` folder:

```el
(package-generate-autoloads "foo" "foo")
```

Much like for any package, it generates in `foo` the `foo-autoloads.el` file, where there is a line:

```el
(autoload 'foofunc "foo" nil nil nil)
```

When restarting Emacs, by inspecting the value of the variable `load-path`, I see that the `foo` is automatically included, being under `site-lisp`. However, evaluating `foofunc`, gives:

```el
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function foofunc)
```

Not surprisingly, if I manually evaluate `(autoload 'foofunc "foo" nil nil nil)` or

```el
(load "foo-autoloads.el")
```

`foofunc` works. However, there should be some way to have this done automatically by Emacs for all autoloads files in the path.

Note that, while this question focuses on `package-generate-autoloads` function, if there is a better way to activate autoloads, your answer is welcomed.

#### Side Question

As a side note, I have seen that applying `package-generate-autoloads` to some ELPA packages adds to the corresponding `*-autoloads.el` files a convenient call to `register-definition-prefix`. As I understand, with this function you can add a custom prefix `mypref-`, such that, whenever you try to autocomplete `mypref-` in the minibuffer, you autoload the relevant lisp file.
What (magic cookies) in the source files trigger(s) the insertion of these calls in the `*-autoloads.el` files?

Answer (score 1):

> This does not seem to be the strategy followed by most packages, which instead create a distinct `*-autoloads.el` file for each source equipped with the magic autoload comments

It is not the package that is responsible for this, but the built-in package manager, `package.el`.

> (perhaps to avoid cluttering `loaddefs.el`).

I'm not familiar with the history behind `-autoloads.el` files, but I'd say they are distinct from `loaddefs.el` so that the former can be automatically detected and loaded by `package.el`.

> However, there should be some way to have this done automatically by Emacs for all autoloads files in the path.

AFAIK, only `package.el` has such a mechanism built-in; see `package-directory-list`:

```el
;;;###autoload
(defcustom package-directory-list
  ;; Defaults are subdirs named "elpa" in the site-lisp dirs.
  (let (result)
    (dolist (f load-path)
      (and (stringp f)
           (equal (file-name-nondirectory f) "site-lisp")
           (push (expand-file-name "elpa" f) result)))
    (nreverse result))
  "List of additional directories containing Emacs Lisp packages.
Each directory name should be absolute.

These directories contain packages intended for system-wide; in
contrast, `package-user-dir' contains packages for personal use."
  :type '(repeat directory)
  :initialize #'custom-initialize-delay
  :risky t
  :version "24.1")
```

So if you put your `foo` package directory under `package-user-dir` or `site-lisp/elpa/` it should be picked up by `package.el` automatically (after calling `package-activate-all`, `package-initialize`, or similar).

Otherwise, I think non-`package.el` loaddefs files need to be explicitly loaded.

> What (magic cookies) in the source files trigger(s) the insertion of these calls in the `*-autoloads.el` files?

The lack of a cookie ;).  The following file:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

;;;###autoload
(defun foo-bar ())

(provide 'foo)
```

will produce only the following autoload:

```el
(autoload 'foo-bar "foo" nil nil nil)
```

There is no need to register a prefix in this case, because Emacs already knows where to find `foo-bar` by virtue of it being autoloaded from a specific file.

OTOH the following file:

```el
;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-

;;;###autoload
(defun foo-bar ())
(defun foo-baz ())

(provide 'foo)
```

results in:

```el
(autoload 'foo-bar "foo" nil nil nil)
(register-definition-prefixes "foo" '("foo-baz"))
```

Comment: Thanks for all your insights. It seems that being under "elpa" is just one condition. `package-initialize` requires `*-pgk.el`, which is autogenerated during the setup process. The main takeaway here is that `package-generate-autoloads` could be not suitable to be used outside package.el framework.

Comment: @antonio Yes, I wanted to emphasise that `package.el` and `autoload.el` should be thought of as separate systems, although the former obviously builds on the latter.