# Using hooks in minor modes

Tags: hooks, major-mode, minor-mode

I have introduced the following hook function inside a minor mode.  The intention is to activate the minor mode for a number of major modes.  I would also need to activate `outline-minor-mode` once `tika-minor-mode` is enabled.  And disable `outline-minor-mode` when `tika-minor-mode` is turned off.

```
;;;###autoload
(defun tika-addhook ()
  "Activate minor-mode' automatically for specific major-modes."
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'tika-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'sh-mode-hook         #'tika-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'f90-mode-hook        #'tika-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'fortran-mode-hook    #'tika-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'latex-mode-hook      #'tika-minor-mode)
  (add-hook 'plain-tex-mode-hook  #'tika-minor-mode))
```

I have the following function for the task

Have seen the use of `;;;###autoload` but I not sure whether it is required to call function after the `require` clause in my `.emacs`.  From what I can understand, a minor mode needs some way to enable its functionality and do not think that `tika-addhook` would execute automatically if it not called after loading the minor mode functionality.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/bin/tika")
(require 'tika)
(tika-addhook)
```

Comment: I'm almost certain this is a duplicate question, but I don't have time to look for it. Please do that, then delete this duplicate. People posting questions *or* answers should really check whether the question has already been posted. Thx.

Comment: @Drew Sorry: did you really say that you don't have time to find a dup but I should somehow find time myself?  OK--I have deleted my answer but shall probably engage with this site a little less.

Comment: Would you have a link to it ?

Comment: @FranBurstall: I'm just a user here, like you. Everyone can look for dup Qs. In particular it's helpful & polite for someone posting a Q to do it. Q&A is for everyone, not just for someone who writes a Q or A. Dup Qs are a bother, and unfair to others, including (1) people searching for As and (2) people who've contributed to the same, but earlier, Qs. It's better for a single Q to have N answers than for multiple Qs to split N answers. To have fewer dups everyone can help out, and yes, that takes time. (I search and vote to close *lots* of Qs here.)

Comment: @FranBurstall: And *I didn't say you should delete your answer.* **Best** is to add it to the same question posed earlier, *if* there is one. But yeah, for that you might have to search a bit. Until someone does that, **second best** is to undelete your answer here, so at least the question is answered, even if it might be a dup. My comment was intended to hopefully help by suggesting that I think this question might be a dup - just a guess. (I've voted to undelete your answer.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling a minor mode in all but some buffers](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50339/enabling-a-minor-mode-in-all-but-some-buffers)

Comment: FWIW: Searching for these 3 tags together shows several duplicate questions: `[major-mode] [minor-mode] [hooks]`. It would be great if Someone(TM) tried to consolidate some of them.

Comment: This question is not about how to make a hook, but about how to write and use a minor-mode in the context of `;;;###autoload`.

Comment: @Randy: “*but about how to write and use a minor-mode in the context of **`;;;###autoload`***” --- So please edit your question (and perhaps the title) to clarify this point and illustrate what confuses you, making it look relatively less like a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have seen the use of ;;;###autoload but I not sure whether it is required to call function after the require clause in my .emacs.

If this is your only real question, then I agree that this is a likely duplicate, though if so then you have included enough irrelevant information to make it harder to tell. Very likely the information you seek is in one of the answers to these questions:

- [When should I use autoload instead of require?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/364/when-should-i-use-autoload-instead-of-require)
- [How to generate and activate autoloads for local packages?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/how-to-generate-and-activate-autoloads-for-local-packages)
- [How does Emacs see the generated autoloads files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77133/how-does-emacs-see-the-generated-autoloads-files)

You might also peruse the list of questions taked “autoload”: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autoload

That said, the answer is pretty simple. Adding autoloads is a way to defer the cost of loading a package until the user actually starts using it. Normally a package `foo` will have a `foo.el` which is as short and simple as possible, generally consisting just of calls to `autoload` that look something like this¹:

```lisp
(autoload 'foo-start "foo-impl")
```

This tells Emacs that the function `foo-start` exists, and that if the user calls it then Emacs must first load a file called `foo-impl.el` which will define it. Then when the user puts `(require 'foo)` in their config file, it will not need to stop and load the whole package at once.

Since keeping that list of autoloads up to date is somewhat annoying, you can call `update-file-autoloads` (or `make-directory-autoloads`) to generate it. This would look for the `;;;###autoload` cookies in your source code.

But a small package won’t benefit from this extra work, so just ignore it and put everything in `foo.el`.

See [chapter 16.5 Autoload](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual for more information.

¹: ELPA (and MEPLA) packages have a different convention; they automatically load `foo-autoloads.el` at startup so that the user doesn’t have to add *anything* to their init file.

Comment: Right.  Meaning that autoload is just a declaration to indicate that a specific function exists.  Because the actual file contents have not been loaded yet, without such declaration, the function call would generate an error because  the required function has not been properly included in the code before attempting to call the function.

Comment: That’s correct. All the `autoload` function does is stash away the information you give it so that if you ever try to call a function that doesn’t exist, it can double check to see if it needs to be autoloaded before throwing an error.

Comment: This also indicates that `(require 'tika)` does not actually load the file but scans it ?

Comment: Where did you get *that* idea? Please read the doc string of `require`.

Comment: No, `require` just loads the file you specify, nothing else. If the file happens to contain calls to the `autoload` function, then those autoloads are registered. Otherwise, there are no autoloads. You can read the docstring of a function with `C-h f`.

Comment: Ok.  Thus, loading a file does not mean that the code within the file is immediately available for use.  Loading a file simply executes the code within it, but the availability of functions and variables defined in that file depends on the scoping rules and when they are evaluated.

Comment: Technically true, but most of the time those complications are irrelevant. 99.99% of the time a file that you load is just a bunch of `defvar`s and `defun`s and everything is evaluated all in one go. If you have more questions about this, search the documentation, search the existing questions, and if you still can’t figure it out then create new questions here on StackExchange. In the long term this kind of back and forth in the comments is unhelpful to others.

Comment: I agree with you.  Using `require` on a file makes the defun's and defvar's available even without `;;;###autoload`.

Comment: Of course, because that’s a comment. Comments don’t change what happens when the file is loaded.